# How to Merge two Observables so the result completes when the any of the Observables completes?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, combinators

I have this code:

```
var s1 = new Subject<Unit>();
var s2 = new Subject<Unit>();
var ss = s1.Merge(s2).Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("Finished!"));

ss.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("Next"));

s1.OnNext(new Unit());
s2.OnNext(new Unit());
s1.OnCompleted(); // I wish ss finished here.
s2.OnCompleted(); // Yet it does so here. =(
```

I've solved my problem using OnError(new OperationCanceledException()), but I'd like a better solution (there has to be a combinator right?).

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't an inbuilt operator, so I've written some extension methods to solve this for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or this, which is also quite neat:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static IObservable<T> MergeWithCompleteOnEither<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<T> right)
    {
        return Observable.CreateWithDisposable<T>(obs =>
        {
            var compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
            var subject = new Subject<T>();

            compositeDisposable.Add(subject.Subscribe(obs));
            compositeDisposable.Add(source.Subscribe(subject));
            compositeDisposable.Add(right.Subscribe(subject));


            return compositeDisposable;

        });     
    }
}
```

This uses a subject which will make sure only one OnCompleted is pushed to the observer in the CreateWithDisposable();

Comment: I'd recommend using an `AsyncSubject`, otherwise you can have a race condition.

Comment: I like this better than the one with Materialize(). @Richard: Can you explain how it could trigger a race?

Comment: Updated.  The race is that when I subscribe the subject to source and right, either could OnComplete and the subject.Subscribe(obs) would miss it.

Comment: When using the AsyncSubject, I loose one of the two OnNext()...and in my real code (observing messages from a MessageQueue) I never get any messages out...yet if I use Subject, I do. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Every time I see an Rx example, it seems so easy!

Comment: Try the updated version pablo.  I've subscribed the subject first, so nothing should be missed.

Comment: Note, I've changed the AsyncSubject back to a Subject

Comment: Note: in the latest Rx release, `Observable.CreateWithDisposable` has been refactored as `Observable.Create` overload

Answer (score 8):

Instead of re-writing Merge to finish when either stream completes I would suggest converting the onCompleted events to onNext events and using `var ss = s1.Merge(s2).TakeUntil(s1ors2complete)` where s1ors2complete produces a value when either s1 or s2 ends. You could also just chain `.TakeUntil(s1completes).TakeUntil(s2completes)` instead of creating s1ors2complete. This approach provides better composition than a MergeWithCompleteOnEither extension as it can be used to modify any "complete when both complete" operator into a "complete when any completes" operator.

As for how to convert onNext events to onCompleted events, there are a few ways to do that. The CompositeDisposable method sounds like a good approach, and a bit of searching finds this interesting thread about [converting between onNext, onError, and onCompleted notifications](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/rx/thread/387d3c5e-5143-4080-a20f-cd7107b34c93). I'd probably create an extension method called ReturnTrueOnCompleted using `xs.SkipWhile(_ => true).concat(Observable.Return(True))` and your merge then becomes:

```
var s1ors2complete = s1.ReturnTrueOnCompleted().Amb(s2.ReturnTrueOnCompleted());
var ss = s1.Merge(s2).TakeUntil(s1ors2complete).Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("Finished!"));
```

You could also look at using an operator like Zip which [automatically completes](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/J.Van.Gogh/Reactive-Extensions-API-in-depth-even-more-Zip) when one of the input streams completes.

Comment: P.S. Here is a good overview of the different way to combine multiple streams using standard operators: http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2010/06/rx-part-5-combining-multiple.html

Comment: Nice approach, and I agree it's better to have one operator that allows me to complete anything than one just for Merge...Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't need the output of either of the streams, you can use `Amb` combined with some magic from `Materialize`:

```
var s1 = new Subject<Unit>();
var s2 = new Subject<Unit>();

var ss = Observable.Amb(
        s1.Materialize().Where(x => x.Kind == NotificationKind.OnCompleted), 
        s2.Materialize().Where(x => x.Kind == NotificationKind.OnCompleted)
    )
    .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("Finished!"));

ss.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("Next"));

s1.OnNext(new Unit());
s2.OnNext(new Unit());

s1.OnCompleted(); // ss will finish here and s2 will be unsubscribed from
```

If you need the values, you can use `Do` on the two subjects.

Comment: This just comes with a cost of the materialize calls, plus as you've said, you're unable to get to the values other than through a side-effecting Do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static IObservable<T> MergeWithCompleteOnEither<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<T> right)
    {
        var completed = Observable.Throw<T>(new StreamCompletedException());

        return 
            source.Concat(completed)
            .Merge(right.Concat(completed))
            .Catch((StreamCompletedException ex) => Observable.Empty<T>());

    }

    private sealed class StreamCompletedException : Exception
    {
    }
}
```

What this does is concatenate an IObservable that will throw an exception when either the source or the right source completes.  We can then use the Catch extension method to return an empty Observable to automatically complete the stream when either completes.

Comment: This was my first attempt, but I think it's not very elegant (I used OperationCanceledException).